# Has there been any guidance for when AS2 might be dropped from the Flash Player?

Tags: flash

AS3 has been out for quite a while now.

The mobile/android flash 10 player does not include AVM1 support (ie Actionscript 2)

Has there been any guidance for when/if AS2 support might be dropped from the desktop plugin?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I i don't think Adobe will drop support for old AS1/AS2 based content for long, since there is so much great old stuff out there, like for instance http://www.weebls-stuff.com/songs/kenya/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no solid answers, I'll answer my own question.

After some more research, I was unable to find any indication one way or another.  My guess is that it's not a worry.